# Unable to restore the Site collection Backup in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, central-administration, backup, restore

I have tried to Restoring the Site collection backup by using Power shell command,it throws an error message

> ```
> Restore-SPSite : The operation that you are attempting to perform cannot be
> completed successfully.  No content databases in the web application were
> available to store your site collection.  The existing content databases may
> have reached the maximum number of site collections, or be set to read-only,
> or be offline, or may already contain a copy of this site collection.  Create
> another content database for the Web application and then try the operation
> again.
> ```

I can Restore my site collection backup only in new web application, I can't in existing web application? how to solve this issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had experienced the same kind of situation and following steps solved it

- create a new content database in desired web application
- now run the restore command with database name parameter. Use the newly created content db.
- test it.